# onReceive of BroadcastReceiver shows alert 2 times in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am implementing internet connectivity lost in my application using BroadcastReceiver.The code is working fine but the alert which is shown on internet connection or disconnection showing twice.I want to show alert or toast only once at a time.Below is my code of Broadcastreceiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")) {
                ConnectivityManager cm =
                        (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                //NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                if (cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
                        || cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

                    // notify user you are online
                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else if (cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED
                        || cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {
                    Constants.alert("Please check your internet connection", context);

                    // notify user you are not online
                }
```

Comment: Add to Toast more debug info: states for every network

Comment: @bukkojot Can you plz provide code hint?

Comment: Something like this, add it in start of onReceive and see at changes:   Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "onReceive: "+intent.getAction()+", mobile:"+cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)+", wifi:"+cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: @bukkojot Actually onreceive is calling twice,as phone send broadcast twice.Any other solution,if u can provide?

Comment: This not final solution, this is way, where you can determine reasons of every call. If you got two same Toasts, you can more deeply inspect your objects and system state. If nothing helps and you always got same results - you can use workaround with static variables.

Answer (score 0):

**Receiving multiple broadcast is a device specific problem. Some phones just send one broadcast while other send 2 or 3. But there is a work around:**

Assuming you get the disconnect message when the wifi is disconnected, I would guess the first one is the correct one and the other 2 are just echoes for some reason.

To know that the message has been called, you could have a static boolean that gets toggled between connect and disconnect and only call your sub-routines when you receive a connection and the boolean is true. Something like:

```
public class ConnectionChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static boolean firstConnect = true;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetInfo != null) {
        if(firstConnect) { 
            // do subroutines here
            firstConnect = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        firstConnect= true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: activeNetInfo this is returning null when internet is off.

Comment: If i remove this if statement than still it shows 2 alert.